# C++ Functions, what im doing wrong

Tags: c++, function, syntax

Im new to this page and a beginner in c++.I can get my code to work, basically my code looks like this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double result(double num1,double num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}
void addition() {
    double num1{};
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    double num2{};
    cout << "Enter second number: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "The result is: " << result << endl;
}
int main() {
    addition();
    return 0;
}
```

Say for example the user inputs 25 as his first and second number so the result should be 50, but it's not. It looks something like this

```
Enter first number: 25
Enter second number: 25
The result is: 006911F9
```

I tried changing from double to int thinking it would help but sadly it didnt. What im a missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the address of the function `result`.

If you want to call the function `result`, use `()` operator.

In other words, change this line

```
    cout << "The result is: " << result << endl;
```

to

```
    cout << "The result is: " << result(num1, num2) << endl;
```